# Error(Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined) when trying to show list data menu with Select2 AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I want to show list data menu when i type words in search box. but there is error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined". can you help me?

This my JS in Views Page:

```
  $("#f_emp").select2(
    {
        ajax: {
            url: '<?=base_url();?>index.php/menu/get_menu_list',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            quietMillis: 1000,
            data: function (term) {

                return {
                    keyword: term

                };
            },
            results: function (data) {

                  return {
                        results: data
                  };
            }
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        placeholder         : "--[ Search Menu ]--"
    }
);
```

This is Menu Model:

```
 function get_menu_by_keyword($keyword){

     $this->db->select('mn.name')
              ->like('mn.name',$keyword);
      return  $this->db->get($this->tableBind.' mn')->result();
}
```

This Is Menu Controller:

```
 function get_menu_list()
{
    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
        if (isset($keyword))
        {
            die(json_encode($this->menu_model->get_menu_by_keyword($keyword)));
        }
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) . _Never_ use user data directly in your queries like that. You should use CI's query builder instead, since it uses prepared statements in the background.

Comment: sorry im new in CI but i already edit my queries in Menu Model. thank you for your advice

Comment: what is `get_menu_list()` outputting? if you don't know how to find this I suggest you check out tutorials on how to use developer tools in your browser.

Comment: please also post model code: `get_menu_by_keyword`

Comment: @Alex This is output of get_menu_list   [{name: "Informasi Pembayaran"}, {name: "Import Master Item"},…]
0: {name: "Informasi Pembayaran"}
1: {name: "Import Master Item"}
2: {name: "View Master Social Responsibility"}
3: {name: "Master"}
4: {name: "HOD - Usia & Masa Kerja Report"}
5: {name: "Informasi Pembayaran"}
6: {name: "Master SM"}
7: {name: "Input Master Social Responsibility"}

Comment: select2 expects output in this form: https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays or for multilevel (like you seem to have it is more complex) http://embed.plnkr.co/fSg6TF/ ... your error is due to you having an incorrect datastructure that select2 can't read

Comment: @Alex when i debug with dev tool of my browser it show the results but still there is an error Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined" so it doesn't show list of menu in search box

Comment: The message "Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined" means that a string was expected in the JS code but the variable was undefined instead. As mentioned by hann, Select2 expects to receive pairs of _ID_ and _text_: `{"id": "ID key"; "text": "Display value"}` as part of a `results` array which mismatches your `{"name": "..."}` format. You may transform your current result into the proper format using `processResults(data)` as described [here](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data).

Comment: oh okay i having incorrect datastructure before and my results array must  pairs of ID and text: {"id": "ID key"; "text": "Display value"} and now it solved! Thank you all